# UIPopoverPresentationController is Null on iOS 10

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, ios10

I managed to show a Popover on iPad with iOS 11 and set the necessary popover properties in ViewDidLoad of my Controller. The only problem I'm facing is when I use an iPad with iOS 10. The popover presenation controller is Null on iOS 10 in ViewDidLoad.

How and where can I set my properties? If I don't set anything the Popover will eventually be shown but on the top left side of the screen since no properties were set.

And did anything change between iOS 10 and 11 that might change the behavior of how the Popover is created?

Comment: I think we can both achieve this on 10 or 11. Can you post some code about how you create the `PopoverPresentationController`?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT It gets created automatically after navigation with IMvxNavigationService.